VueJS3 on firefox blocks image requests on localhost for exactly 2 seconds on route change
I have been having a problem with VueJS where images that should be loaded on route change only load after precisely 2 seconds no matter the image. This only happens on Firefox and not on Chromium Edge or Chrome.
A screenshot of the Firefox developer tools
I am aware that I have not posted any code here. I do not know which parts may cause this, therefore I do not know which parts of the project to share. I hope some of you have encountered this issue before and know what might be causing this issue.

Images take 2 seconds to load on route change during which the request is marked as 'blocked' (see screenshot).
On localhost (vite dev server), images are located in the public folder of the project
Only on Firefox not on Chromium based browsers like Chrome or Chromium Edge
It only happens for images that are not cached

I am using Vue 3.4.19 with Vue-Router 4.2.5
I have disabled all watchers and middleware associated with the Vue Router and the problem still persists. Additionally, I can confirm that there are no timeouts of 2 seconds or similar inside the project.

This is the actual problem with unsupported browsers. It could be the limit of concurrent connections, which may differ between browsers and can be configured. Previously this wasn't the problem for FF but I can't say if it changed. The important detail that you omitted is the way the app is served. Is it devserver or prod, and which server exactly?

Thank you for your reply, it is running on a Vite dev server. I also figured out that just viewing an image directly (https://example.com/static/img/example.png) already takes exactly 2 seconds. This should not interact with any code as it is just a static image. This makes me believe it should not exceed the concurrent connections of Firefox

I can confirm this is the case on Windows for any latest Vite setup, not just Vue, and FF 99 and 123, but not 48. localhost:5173/example.png consistently results in 2s delay, unless it's cached. Well, this was my point about unsupported browsers, unfortunately. Good to know. I'd suggest to open an issue in both Vite repo and Bugzilla
